# How to create custom operators with precedence

Tags: scala

I hava a class with custom Operators

```
case class Num(var value:Int) {
    def add(x:Num) = Num(value + x.value)
    def mul(x:Num) = Num(value * x.value)
  }
```

So I can call them like this

```
val a = Num(2)
val b = Num(3)
val c = Num(4)
val m1 = a add b mul c
```

But how can I execute `mul` before `add`? I saw a solution like `+|` instead of `add`, but I want include letters in my Operator and `+add` and `*mul` not working. Also I want to include a `pow` function, so this needs an higher precidence than `mul`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Parenthesis after add.

```
val m1 = a add (b mul c) = 14
val m1 = a add b mul c = 20
```

**Update**

you do not have any restrictions in naming your methods. For example, you can define methods +, -, * and etc. for a class.

```
case class Num(var value:Int) {
    def + (x:Num) = Num(value + x.value)
    def *(x:Num) = Num(value * x.value)
  }

  object Num  extends App {
    val a = Num(2)
    val b = Num(3)
    val c = Num(4)
    val m1 = a + b * c
    println(m1)

}
```

**Output**

```
Num(14)
```

Comment: Yes, but in longer expressions, this looks not good. Are there a way to do this with the operators?

Comment: The problem is, if I name the functions not like this,  e.g. mul instead of * , the output will be 20

Comment: What is the problem defining function name as `*` and `+` instead of `mul` and `add`.

Comment: I want to add functions like pow, integral and root. For this I need precedence, too.

Comment: Operator precedence is fixed in the Scala Reference - 6.12.3 Infix Operations by the first character in the operator.
 https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#infix-operations

Comment: Scala do not support `*mul` you should use `*`. It is described in the link above.

And,pow and root are essentially the same operation, expressed differently (similar to binary + and -). I.e., sqrt(a) is the same as pow(a, 0.5), just like a + b is the same as a - (-b). So I'd say they should have equal precedence, and hence be evaluated left-to-right.
So, I don't think you will get any problem using `+`  and `*` instead of `add` and `mul` and so on.

Comment: @Rip: alphanumeric and operator characters in a method name must be separated by an underscore. Otherwise, it would not be possible to distinguish between, e.g. `!foo` meaning "not foo" (i.e. syntactic sugar for `foo.unary_!()`) and `!foo` meaning "call the method named `!foo`". So, `*` is a valid method name, `mul` is a valid name, but `*mul` is not. However `*_mul` is.

Comment: This doesn't work. The error message is: ```Error:(77, 10) '=' expected but identifier found.
    def *_mul(x:Num) = {``` _________AND________ ```Error:(83, 1) Missing closing brace `}` assumed here
}```  ________AND_________  ```Error:(83, 1) illegal start of simple expression
}```

Comment: @Rip: Sorry, you are right. An identifier that starts with an operator character can only consist of operator characters. Identifiers that start with a letter can contain an underscore and either further letters and numbers or operator characters after the underscore. This just goes to show that you should rather trust [the documentation](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/01-lexical-syntax.html#identifiers) than random people on the Internet. So, `mul_*` is a valid identifier. Of course, you can always quote invalid identifiers.